# Identify a sample in "Summertime" by Jazzy Jeff & The Fresh Prince?

Tags: identify-this-sample

I'm curious what the origin of main background-persistent sample in the DJ Jazzy Jeff & The Fresh Prince (Will Smith) song [*Summertime*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Summertime_%28DJ_Jazzy_Jeff_%26_The_Fresh_Prince_song%29) is from? It's sort of familiar to me as something reminiscent of some electronic charging noise but I can't quite get it.

Link to the song [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Kr0tTbTbmVA).

Can you guys think of any potential origins where that background persistent portamento synth is from or may be inspired or derived from?

Comment: Do you mean the portamento synth?

Comment: Yes, after looking that up, that's the thing I'm looking for, yeah.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It's from the end of Kool and the Gang's [*Summer Madness*](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=2SFt7JHwJeg#t=237).

[Whosampled](http://www.whosampled.com/DJ-Jazzy-Jeff-%26-the-Fresh-Prince/Summertime) only lists two sources for the song, and one is only used for drums, so that narrowed it down a lot!